# heap size error in Python when using POSTagger

Tags: python, pos-tagger

In python IDE (PYCHARM), I am using stanford POSTagger to retrieve the part of speech of 200 files however it keeps giving me heap size error, and I have changed xmx6g in idea.vmoptions (which is located at Library/preferences/Pycharm30/idea.vmoptions )
But still it is not helping. I wonder how can I tackle it? I appreciate any comment on how to solve it, again I am writing my code in Pycharm.